# How to place my message where I want it using php

Tags: php, html, forms

this is the code I have, I need my message to appear in the top of my form but I got an error.
I need to print my message right where I put the code print $msg

any idea about this please.

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
      <table width="300" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><?php print($msg); ?></td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
          <td> *First name</td>
          <td><span id="sprytextfield3">
            <input type="text" value="" name="RFname" />
            <br>
            <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>*Last name</td>
          <td><span id="sprytextfield4">
            <input type="text" value="" name="RLname" />
            <br>
            <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>*User name</td>
          <td><span id="sprytextfield1">
            <input type="text" name="UserName" value="" />
            <br />
            <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>*Password</td>
          <td><span id="sprypassword1">
            <input type="password" name="UserPass" value="" />
            <span class="passwordRequiredMsg"><br />
            A value is required.</span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>*Email</td>
          <td><span id="sprytextfield2">
            <input type="text" name="UserEmail" value="" />
            <br />
            <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Web site</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="WebSite" value="" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td><input name="submited" type="submit" onClick="MM_swapImage('Image1','','images/blog.png',1)" value="Register"/></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div class="image_NewUserRegister"><iframe src="images/Untitled-2.jpg" name="now_regist" width="207" height="280" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>
  </div>
  <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submited'])) {
            $RFname = $_POST['RFname'];
            $RLname = $_POST['RLname'];
            $USERname = $_POST['UserName'];
            $USERpassword = $_POST['UserPass'];
            $USERemail = $_POST['UserEmail'];
            $USERwebsite = $_POST['WebSite'];

            $check=$db->query("select 1 from loginaccess where Email ='".$USERemail."'");

            if(mysqli_num_rows($check) > 0 ) {
                $msg = "<span style='color:#F00; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;'>This email already taken</span>";
                }
```

this is the code I have, I need my message to appear in the top of my form but I got an error. I need to print my message right where I put the code print $msg

any idea about this please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need to set the message *before* you try to output it.

Comment: Silly people, wanting their horses to precede their carts... :]

Comment: Tieson T. thanks for the replay but I came here to solve something not to be silly anyway I will try to do what you just told me it will take from me time to adjust every thing in my code page because it's big Thanks again dear Tieson T. for you great post

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on David's answer: move the PHP block before the form markup, like so:

```
  <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submited'])) {
            $RFname = $_POST['RFname'];
            $RLname = $_POST['RLname'];
            $USERname = $_POST['UserName'];
            $USERpassword = $_POST['UserPass'];
            $USERemail = $_POST['UserEmail'];
            $USERwebsite = $_POST['WebSite'];

            $check=$db->query("select 1 from loginaccess where Email ='".$USERemail."'");

            if(mysqli_num_rows($check) > 0 ) {
                $msg = "<span style='color:#F00; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;'>This email already taken</span>";
            }
  ?>
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
      <table width="300" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><?php print($msg); ?></td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
          <td> *First name</td>
          <td><span id="sprytextfield3">
            <input type="text" value="" name="RFname" />
            <br>
            <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>*Last name</td>
          <td><span id="sprytextfield4">
            <input type="text" value="" name="RLname" />
            <br>
            <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>*User name</td>
          <td><span id="sprytextfield1">
            <input type="text" name="UserName" value="" />
            <br />
            <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>*Password</td>
          <td><span id="sprypassword1">
            <input type="password" name="UserPass" value="" />
            <span class="passwordRequiredMsg"><br />
            A value is required.</span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>*Email</td>
          <td><span id="sprytextfield2">
            <input type="text" name="UserEmail" value="" />
            <br />
            <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span><span class="textfieldInvalidFormatMsg">Invalid format.</span></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Web site</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="WebSite" value="" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td><input name="submited" type="submit" onClick="MM_swapImage('Image1','','images/blog.png',1)" value="Register"/></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div class="image_NewUserRegister"><iframe src="images/Untitled-2.jpg" name="now_regist" width="207" height="280" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>
  </div>
```

HTH.

Comment: Thanks Tieson T. but aren't any way else to solve this without moving my block on the top I am sure there is a way

Comment: There are certainly other ways, you can change `print($msg);` to a call to a function in your PHP code the generates the message.

Comment: @Yousef No, there is not. The variable does not get assigned to until the script has run. This is pure sequential programming. EDIT: David has a point, but as-is, I still think the answer is "no."